# How do I find the total occurrences of an element in JSON array string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, performance

I am trying to find the total frequency of an element in a JSON array column using SQL. I did come up with this solution-

```
 rewards    user_id
[1, 2, 2]      1
[1, 2, 3]      1
-------------------
SELECT SUM(JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(rewards, 'all', '2'))) AS total
    FROM tbl_answer
    WHERE user_id = 1
      AND JSON_CONTAINS(rewards, '2') = 1;
```

result

```
total
  3
```

But something's telling me there is a much better way. I would appreciate any suggestions you may have on this.

Comment: In general, JSON should be reserved for data that you do _not_ need to include in a `WHERE` clause.  So, I recommend rethinking the schema.

Comment: yeah, I ended up making a history records table and count from there.